# Get GPS Coordinates When an Arcore Plane Is Tapped

Tags: android, arcore, android-gps

I'm new to ARCore and I'm trying to achieve a GPS-based AR. Basically, the app will render a 3D object and get its GPS coordinates (Lat/Lng)

App basic flow:

1. OnTapArPlaneListener - render a 3D object -> This is available in
   ARCore sample project, so I have no issue doing this
2. Get Location (Lat/Lng) of the tapped plane -> This probably requires transforming screen x,y,z and I don't know yet how to achieve it

I've tried this library: https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location but I believe this won't help because it places the 2D image not the 3D

Is it possible to get the Lat/Lng of a tapped plane?

Thank  you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be with the distance of the point from the device - depth or distance measurement is not really supported in most devices at this time, or not in a consistent hardware depth sensor based way.

There are some add on HW solutions (e.g. https://structure.io) and software frameworks which have some depth and occlusion capability (e.g. https://www.6d.ai/product) but I'm not sure these will meet your availability or accuracy needs.

On workaround, which is crude but may meet your needs: if you are able to ensure that the point being tapped is a set distance from the device then you can just:

- Ask the user to tap at set distance from device
- Get location of device from its built in GPS
- Add the set distance, in the correct orientation, to the location

Not very sophisticated but may be enough for some use cases.